# Maximum Likelihood Function with X having the same distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Given all $X_i$ have the same distribution (say, Normal distribution), when we are calculating the maximum likelihood function, we obtain:

$= . . .= \frac{1}{{2\pi}^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{-1}{2}} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \cdot g (t(x), \theta)$

Can we simply multiply the $X_i^2$ with $n$, as they have the same distribution ?

(i.e., into this:  $\frac{1}{{2\pi}^{\frac{n}{2}}}\cdot e^{\frac{-1}{2}} \cdot n X^2$)

why or why not?

Comment: sorry, it's a typo

Comment: X represents a single normal distribution, I guess they are the same would be the dependence relationship ?

Comment: Ummm.. I'm not sure. I actually don't really understand the marginal relationship part. Is there any reference that I can read?

Comment: No I guess :( since we have taken the log and derivation with respect to \mu and \sigma

Comment: Welcome to the site. Are the $X_i$s your observations? What does $X^2$ mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. You haven't defined what is $X$.

We compute likelihood based on the collected data.

Also, $X_1 + X_2$ is also different from $2X_1$. In the first case, you are summing up two observations, in the second case, you are discarding a reading and just multiply the first one by $2$.  These two statistics behave differently. For example if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d, $Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)= 2Var(X_1)$ but $Var(2X_1)=4Var(X_1)$.